# django-allauth redirects again to signup/login forms

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am using django-allauth for local account management. I have customized templates ,login.html and signup.html. Both of these templates are placed in templates/account/ dir and both are accessible properly. 
site root i.e **localhost:8000** points to index.html which includes using **{% include%}** both the templates on main page.

form action for signup form in signup.hmtl is set to **action="{% url 'account_signup' %}"** and that of login.html is set to **"{% url 'account_login' %}"**

Both the templates appears OK on the main page. The problem arises when I try to use these forms for sigin/login. Instead processing the POST for signup or login I am redirected to **locahost:8000/accounts/signup/** for signup and **localhost:8000/accounts/login/** for login. I guess I am using the right urls that is **account_signup** and **account_login**

I have all settings for allauth. Is this is the default behaviour or I'm missing some thing out? Thanking in anticipation

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to get rid of the problem after spending some hours. Just in case that some one else caughtup in the same situation I would like to share my solution. The problem was forms have been instantiated by View by using prefix `SignUpForm(prefix=signupform)` and  for that reason allauth class `AjaxCapableProcessFormViewMixin(object)` (which I don't know how it works) was unable to get data from the fields and its `if form.is_valid()` was always false as the form has error messages dictionary was containing **this field is required** for all the fields in the form. Jus to test I removed `Prefixing` from the form instantiation and it worked but make me feel strange as these kind of hidden errors can take upto indefinite time to resolve especially for some niwbie like me

```
class AjaxCapableProcessFormViewMixin(object):

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       form_class = self.get_form_class()
       form = self.get_form(form_class)
       if form.is_valid():
           response = self.form_valid(form)
       else:
           response = self.form_invalid(form)
       return _ajax_response(self.request, response, form=form)
```